# Quartz Clustering issue

Tags: cluster-computing, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

Scenario: I have two different modules (say A and B). 
A is deployed on two different machines(say A1 and A2) and B is deployed in two different machines.(say B1 and B2) and a job related to A module is scheduled and the required java-classes are only with A (so both A1 and A2 has it).

I am using spring framework quartz bean and start a scheduler on all the machines as soon as the modules start on the tomcat.

All these information gets stored in the database tables related to quartz.

Best part: During/before execution if A1 goes down, luckily if the scheduler find A2 free, the job will be executed on A2. All the required classes are present on A2, so no problem. SUCCESS!

Bad Part: During/before execution if A1 goes down, UNluckily if the scheduler finds B1 and B2 free, the job will be executed on either of them, but since the required classes are not present on B1/B2, i get a class not found exception. FAILURE!

Query: How do I ensure that jobs related to module A runs only on those machines where A is deployed and not on machines where B is deployed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Solved:** In quartz.properties file. Set the property tablePrefix as follows:

org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ_ 
eg for module A: A_QRTZ_ and for module B: B_QRTZ_

In the database drop all the tables starting with QRTZ_ and create new tables with prefix A_QRTZ_ and B_QRTZ_

So Module-A will access only A_QRTZ_ tables and module will access only B_QRTZ_ tables under the above mentioned scenario.

The number of tables will increase, but ultimately, the the total number of rows/data saved in these tables will be the same as before.